# Is there a standard Windows dialog for obtaining the proxy username and password?

Tags: c++, c, windows, proxy, winhttp

I'm using `WinHTTP` to write an an app that needs access to the internet, and is potentially behind a proxy. Everything works (almost) out of the box is the user is on a domain, but if he or she isn't then I need a way to ask for credentials. Is there a standard way of doing that, or should I write my own dialog?

Ideally I'd like something that mimics IE's username/password dialog.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CredUIPromptForCredentials()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177%28VS.85%29.aspx) (or one of its variants) is probably what you're looking for.  This provides a consistent look and feel with the version of Windows your software is running on.

Comment: Actually I need to call `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` to get the Vista look. Thanks.